# Calculate a definite integral using an expression of another integral

Tags: calculus

[image]

So when the way I thought I would go about solving this problem would be to find the indefinite integrals of the problems first. For the first integral, I got:

$(1/5120)((1/128)sin(2x)-2940sin(6x)+11388sin(10x)+795sin(14x)+965sin(18x))(sec(2x))^10 + 630ln(cos(x)-sin(x)) - 630ln(sin(x)+cos(x)) + C$

For the second integral, I got:

$(1/61440)((-1/512)(-422730sin(2x) + 683958sin(6x) + 15741sin(10x) + 223773sin(14x) + 15895sin(18x) + 11895sin(22x))sec^12(2x) - 6930ln(cos(x) - sin(x)) + 6930ln(ln(sin(x) + cos(x)) + C$

After this, I'm not sure where to go. I see that $I * (1/20)$ could world for the first fraction's relationship to the second one, but I'm in a rut after that. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like it would be doable using integration by parts, rather than finding each integral and looking for a relation between them.

Comment: Or maybe using some identity relating tangents and secants.

Comment: Use backslash before functions like sin,cos,ln, sec etc. It will look much nicer.

Comment: etree-- Did you get a chance to look at my answer below? Let me know if you'd like more details.

Comment: Sorry, just logged back in. Are you saying that I should take J as a definite integral and calculate the limits, then the final answer will still have an element of I in it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let $J$ be the indefinite version of the second integral (with $\tan^{12}$ in it). To apply inetration by parts to $J$ use $u=\tan^{11}(2x)$ and $dv=\sec(2x)\tan(2x).$ Then $v=(1/2)\sec(2x)$ and $du=11 \tan^{10}(2x)\cdot 2.$ Then by the parts rule we get to
$$ J = \tan^{11}(2x)\cdot (1/2)\sec(2x) - 11 \ I.$$
In this you can insert the given limits on the integral and non-integral portions, which means after that $I$ and $J$ are the integrals with the limits on them while the "function" part (The $u v$ section of parts) is to be evaluated at upper and lower limits and those subtracted.